# Error exception caught on transport layer [NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=/x:40554, remoteAddress=/y:9300}], closing connection

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, netty, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am using elastic search and spring data search , I have configured elastic search in an EC2  instance so inititally i put network host  as 0.0.0.0 but then i bind it to network host which is the private ip of the instance , and from that i am getting this error. ALthough if i make a curl on http://pvtIp:9200 it works and same http://pvtIp:9200/nodes returns me the transport layer as the private ip only but it still does not work . I checked that if in my elastic beanstalk instance where my code is hosted any elastic search is configured of any kind but its not present

Also to note that this error only triggers when i am moving the code to server, even during the jenkins buiding the job this issue comes

i did : `sudo service elasticsearch status` it does not identify elastic search
even `sudo netstat -ntlp` returns no port which are open for 9200 and 9300

full stack trace below :

```
    2020-09-11 12:34:04.941  WARN 25875 --- [ient_boss][T#2]] o.e.transport.netty4.Netty4Transport     : exception caught on transport layer [NettyTcpChannel{localAddress=/<private-ip-beanstalk>:40554, remoteAddress=/<private-ip-ec2-where-elasticsearch-is-hosted>:9300}], closing connection

java.io.IOException: Invalid string; unexpected character: 180 hex: b4
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readString(StreamInput.java:402) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readCollection(StreamInput.java:959) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readList(StreamInput.java:941) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.io.stream.StreamInput.readMapOfLists(StreamInput.java:511) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:380) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ThreadContextStruct.<init>(ThreadContext.java:366) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext.readHeaders(ThreadContext.java:200) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.messageReceived(TcpTransport.java:1424) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4MessageChannelHandler.channelRead(Netty4MessageChannelHandler.java:64) ~[transport-netty4-client-6.4.3.jar!/:6.4.3]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:324) [netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.fireChannelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:311) [netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:425) [netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:276) [netty-codec-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.handler.logging.LoggingHandler.channelRead(LoggingHandler.java:271) [netty-handler-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:615) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:578) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493) [netty-transport-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989) [netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) [netty-common-4.1.50.Final.jar!/:4.1.50.Final]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_252]
```

Comment: btw, why do you try to use the transport client? It is deprecated, you rather should be using the Rest client and port 9200

Comment: I have not any code or method in which I am making using of transport but still it's failing

Comment: then remove these lines from your configuration: spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-name=my-application
spring.data.elasticsearch.cluster-nodes=localhost:9300
They are configuring the transport client

Comment: Ok i will try without that , I don't think without that it should work but I will give a try

Comment: I tried so i removed that it looks in localhost but the node is in different address and gives error none of the configured nodes is available which is correct the node cluster is in the y ip which i just removed from property files

Comment: it still is not clear what you are configuring: on what machine with which address is Elasticsearch running? On what machine with which address is the application running? Should the application use the transport client (port 9300) or rest client (9200) to communicate with Elasticsearch?

Comment: @P.J.Meisch My elastic search is running on ec2 instance private ip both the transport node and the search url . I think it is required  to run on port 9200 and 9300

Comment: You do not answer the questions. And you do not need both ports. You either communicate with the transport client or the rest client

Comment: @P.J.Meisch I am also working for the first time in elastic search so i am also not confident how it works